# update data in existing table

Tags: sql, import, append, updates

I'm wanting import data regularly into a table on sql server.  Some existing entries in the table will need to be updated with future imports.  e.g. date of 'file closure' & 'outcome'.

I'm hoping someone could point in the direction of sql that would append new data to the existing table, and well as update any existing entries that have changed.

Thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

you append data with  e.g

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
  VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

and you update with

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
  WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

if you always do an UPDATE first, you can see on the outcome, if the column does not exist. Then you do an insert

Comment: can you use UPDATE when you don't have WHERE conditions?  The issue is that multiple columns may change between updates, to multiple other possible outcomes - So I'm looking for some way to compare all the new data with the existing data from the previous import and only update information that has changed.

Comment: if you UPDATE without WHERE all rows will be updated.